# Using the pd.read_csv, all the data is in the first column. Other columns show NaN

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv

Using read_csv(), I am getting the following results

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data.head()
```

Output:

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|
|-----|-----|-----|
|1,2,3| NaN | NaN |
|6,5,4| NaN | NaN |
```

I tried mentioning sep=',' but it didn't work
After some investigation, I found out that basically the rows are enclosed in string quotes.
like,

> **1, 2, 3** is stored as **'**1, 2, 3**'**

I tried my luck using vectorized string methods

```
df['col_1'].str.replace("'", "").astype(float)
```

But it throws me an error a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

My desired output is simply

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|
|-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
|  6  |  5  |  4  |
```

Thanks

EDIT:
this is the sample of the data I took from the CSV

"6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1"
"1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0"
"8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1"
"1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0"
"0,137,40,35,168,43.1,2.288,33,1"
"5,116,74,0,0,25.6,0.201,30,0"
"3,78,50,32,88,31.0,0.248,26,1"

Comment: Can you share your csv as text that can be used to reproduce the read csv call and the subsequent error in your approach?

Comment: ok, do you want me to share the csv?

Comment: @letdatado yes please, [edit] and add at least the first rows

Comment: Just some plain text copied into the question would be fine. It's just helpful to see the actual input rather than the results of the read.

Comment: I copied a slice from Excel and tried to paste it here but it returned an image

Comment: FYI: This is the famous pima diabetes dataset. I am sure you must have heard about it

Comment: So that's a _column_ in Excel and _not_ a csv?

Comment: Don't give an excel export, a CSV file is a text file, so share the raw data please. Because excel may interpret the data and that won't help us to make the python code works

Comment: Alright. my apologies.

Comment: I GOT THE TEXT VERSION
editting the question guys. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **quotechar = "*quotation*"** in `pd.read_csv` and it will be fine!! ;)

This way

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', quotechar="'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes are used in CSV files to signal that comma separated values should be kept together in a single column. You could create a new CSV file and write a script to read every line of the original file (with the quotes) into a string, remove the leading and trailing quotes from the string, and write the new string into your new CSV file. You could then call `read_csv` on the new CSV file. This should fix the issue.

```
write_text = ''

with open('data.csv', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line[-1] == '\n':
            line = line[0:-1]
        line = line[1:-1]  # remove quotes
        write_text += line + '\n'
write_text = write_text[0:-1]  # remove trailing newline

with open('data_without_quotes.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(write_text)
```

Comment: I tried it by using df['col_1'].str.replace("'", "").astype(float)

Comment: I don't think this approach will fill the remaining two columns with the correct values.

Comment: Maybe you can try manually removing the quotes in the first couple of lines and see if this fixes the issue in just the first two lines of the DataFrame.

Comment: That's why I have come to the rescue lol

Comment: Nikhil, actually I am practicing and I guess I should better know the right trick rather than doing it manually. There should be some way. 
And i definitely agree that I am not doing it correctly

Comment: Also, from the Excel screenshot you have posted, it seems that Excel is also grouping each row in a single column. Try opening the csv in notepad and see if each line is enclosed in quotes.

Comment: yes it is. Each line is double quoted.

Comment: In that case following my original answer should work.

Comment: Ok, let me try it... though i am not comfortable with the writing such code but I should do it myself

Comment: open_file = open('pima.csv',encoding="utf8")

read_file = reader(open_file)

pima = list(read_file)

pima


Using this code, I successfully got into it and returned with a list of the lists structure.

Comment: how to remove the quotes from each list now?

Comment: I'll shortly edit my answer to provide some code

Comment: Nikhil, I got it solved. Don't spend a lot of time on coding if you are. Trick is to use quotechar="'" in read_csv.
 Thanks a lot!

Comment: I saw that you had found the solution too late. Anyways, if you want to fix the csv file itself, you have my code now.